# Calculate work from Force and time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, time

Everywhere it states, that time does not matter when calculating work, but can't you do this:
$$F=ma$$
so $a=F/m$
taking the second integral (dt): $$s=\frac{1}{2}\frac{F}{m}t^2$$ since Force is constant.
now plugging that into $W=Fs$:
$$W=\frac{1}{2}\frac{F^2}{m}t^2$$
Now you can put the m, F and t into the equation and get W.
Did I do a mistake or is it possible to do this?

Comment: For a constant force, and therefore a constant acceleration, the displacement indeed depends upon the duration of time in the way you demonstrate. More the time $t$, more is the displacement $s(t)\sim t^2$ and hence more is the work done. For the same reason, the kinetic energy must also go like $\sim t^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct - assuming no other force act.

The general statement:
$$W=F\cdot s$$
holds for the work done by the force $F$ but also permits other forces to be present.

The above formula is indeed independent of $t$, however if $F$ is the only force then greater $t$ means greater $s$ so greater $W$.

A better statement would be that:

> time does not matter when calculating work provided that the distance covered remains the same.

In your calculation the distance covered changes.